# AWS amplify set up in kotlin unresolved reference errors

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, kotlin, aws-amplify

I am having issues setting up AWS amplify for my kotlin android app. I followed all the steps on their website but my code still does not want to complile.

I'm getting "unresolved reference" errors at any reference of amplify, log or AWSDataStorePlugin in my MainActivity where it specifies to include the config code. I'm also getting "cannot resolve method" errors in the generated java file for my table.

I'm not sure how to fix this as I followed the instructions as told and none of this is my own code. I proceded to deploy the back end but that has not resolved the issue.

```
try {
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSApiPlugin()) // UNCOMMENT this line once backend is deployed
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin())
        Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
        Log.i("Amplify", "Initialized Amplify")
    } catch (e: AmplifyException) {
        Log.e("Amplify", "Could not initialize Amplify", e)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've added the necessary dependencies to your app's build.gradle, in the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.24.0'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:1.24.0'
}
```

Then, make sure to click the "Sync Project with Gradle files" button in Android Studio.

Last, make sure you have the necessary import statements in your source file.  For each "unresolved reference", place your cursor on the reference, type Option+Return, and then select "Import".  This should automatically add the following import statements to the top of your source file:

```
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.AWSDataStorePlugin
import com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AWSApiPlugin
import android.util.Log
```